# What's the difference between normal potting soil and specialty "Mediterranean" potting soil?

Tags: containers, citrus, potting-soil

I have been looking at the labels on specialty potting soil label as "Mediterranean" potting soil for plants such as olive and citrus.

The only real difference besides the huge price difference I have been able to discern is that the specialty potting soil contains (pine) bark which is said to lower the PH. Is this just a scam or are there any other differences?

Comment: Are you talking about Compo potting soil for mediterranean plants?

Comment: I live in Sweden and we don't have the same brands. But Compo looks about the same as the brands I have looked at.

Comment: Well if the one you looked at was similar, with clay and sand, then that's why its more expensive - most potting composts do not contain soil, be it clay or otherwise, and that clay content has to be sterilised to be included in the mix.

Comment: The regular potting soil that I buy contains sand. Its not the cheapest brand, but not very expensive either.

Comment: No clay content then... in the UK, we use John Innes composts for particular plants, especially long term potted plants, which contains loam, another version of soil, and that's more expensive than the general purpose stuff. But some people just use the general purpose stuff anyway.

Comment: @Bamboo How important is clay content to citrus plants (Citrus japonica)?

Comment: Clay or loam is a valuable component in a potting mix to many plants, simply because it holds onto nutrients well, takes up fluid (water) rapidly, yet drains freely. Many soilless muilti purpose composts are difficult to wet once dry, may hold onto water too long, or may allow everything, including nutrients, to drain from the pot too quickly. Clay or soil content is valuable for any long term potted woody plant, including citrus, rather than just being good for citrus.